# Confuse about the overlap and collision between React and D3

Tags: d3.js, reactjs

All:

I am pretty new to React, what I am trying to do is turn a D3 data visualization chart into React Component, but there is one confuses:

I do not quite understand React's virtualDOM, but one thing I believe is D3 can not directly do operation on it(only real DOM can be operated by D3, right?), then the question is:

How can we take full advantage of React? If this is not true, could anyone show me some code that use both D3 and virtualDOM to make a chart with data updating operation and animation transition

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that D3 does not operate on React's virtual DOM, and that D3 is therefore not directly compatible with react. This is unfortunate, but there are essentially two ways around it.

1) Make it operate on the virtual dom. `react-faux-dom` does a good job of this, and makes a lot of D3 work make sense in the context of react.
https://github.com/Olical/react-faux-dom

2) Use an escape hatch, and manipulate the dom directly. Essentially, intercept new props in `componentWillReceiveProps` and set `shouldComponentUpdate` to always return false. From there, take the data from `componentWillRecieveProps` and do what you want with dom refs to the d3 elements.

Neither case is particularly beautiful. There isn't a perfect solution for doing D3 inside of react applications yet.

Comment: Thanks, so say if we forget the D3 DOM manipulation, just leave its math part, could you tell me how can I manipulate those virtualDOM with transition animation like in D3?

Comment: If you're using `react-faux-dom`, you might have some luck using [`react-motion`](https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion). If you're using the escape hatch, then everything should work as it would outside of react, so you can do what you would do as if you were not in a react application. You just have to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

I find the simplest thing to do is to load a d3 visualization inside a React component with `componentDidMount()`. You can then (within the d3 code) access React properties and state, passing data back and forth between them. [Here is an example.](http://codepen.io/dave004/pen/jrZbmK)

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach in which React handles real SVG elements and D3 just doing math. Example from the Internet:

```
class Line extends React.Component {
    static contextTypes = {
        xScale: React.PropTypes.func,
        yScale: React.PropTypes.func
    };

    render() {
        let path = d3.svg.line()
                         .interpolate("linear")
                         .x(d => this.context.xScale(d.x))
                         .y(d => this.context.yScale(d.y));

        return (
            <path d={path(this.props.data)}
                  stroke="#0077CC"
                  strokeWidth="3"
                  fill="none" />
        );
    }
}

class Chart extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        width: React.PropTypes.number,
        height: React.PropTypes.number,
        data: React.PropTypes.shape({
            x: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            y: React.PropTypes.number.isRequired
        }).isRequired
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        width: 400,
        height: 200
    };

    static childContextTypes = {
        xScale: React.PropTypes.func,
        yScale: React.PropTypes.func
    };

    getChildContext() {
        return {
            xScale: this.getXScale(),
            yScale: this.getYScale()
        }
    }

    getXScale() {
        return d3.scale.linear()
                 .domain(d3.extent(this.props.data, d => d.x))
                 .range([0, this.props.width]);
    }

    getYScale() {
        return d3.scale.linear()
                 .domain(d3.extent(this.props.data, d => d.y))
                 .range([this.props.height, 0]);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <svg style={{ width: this.props.width, height: this.props.height }}>
                <Line data={this.props.data} />
            </svg>
        );
    }
}
```